# How to Get specific Call Value in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm actually using a GridView table to show some product properties like Name, Price and Quantity. Then, when calling the `Datashow_RowUpdating` function I minus the value of the Quantity cell. Now I want to get the name of the same product and save it in a list and print it, but I'm not able to get the name of the product. I tried different methods like `Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();`,
but no luck. I attached the update function which contains the code of update, Please Help!!!!! 
Thanks

```
protected void Datashow_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            //ObjectQuery<Med> filteredproduct = new ObjectQuery<Med>("Select Value p From Med AS p ",Med);
            //LstProductsChosen.DataSource = products;
            //LstProductsChosen.DataValueField = "ID";
            //LstProductsChosen.DataTextField = "Name";


            sqlcon.Open();
            string query = "UPDATE Med SET Quantity = Quantity - @Quantity WHERE ID=@id";
            //Med q = new Med { Name = "eee" , Company = "new" };
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", (Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextQuantity") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", (Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextQuantity") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox).Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Convert.ToInt32(Datashow.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Datashow.EditIndex = -1;
            populategridview();
            Addinlist();
            GridViewRow row = Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            string c = Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Med q = new Med()
            {
                Name = c ,
                Price = 100,
                Company = "Reck",
                Discount = 10,
                Expiry = 2018,
                Potency = "30",
                Quantity = 10,
                Size = "10ml"
            };
            meds.Add(q);
            LstProductsChosen.Items.Add("q" + q.Name);

            //LblSucessMsg.Text = "selected " + row.Cells[2].Text;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LblSucessMsg.Text = "";
        LblErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: i Tried this code to put value in the cell just to make it sure that it works. Datashow.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text =" New Name" ; and it shows the "New Name " in the 1st cell of 2nd row. Means it can set the text of the cell. but when i use the same code to get the value of the cell like this string c= Datashow.Rows[2].Cells[1].Text, it does not show any thing why it is not getting the Text of the same cell ...  When i use the methods like Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextName").ToString() it shows  this System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label  instead of the call's Text.

Comment: When i try this code :
String c = Datashow.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0].ToString();
it does not save the value of the Text value of the Cell but saves
This line in string c: System.Web.UI.LiteralControl

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to get the current selected row:

```
GridViewRow row = DataShow.SelectedRow;

// And you respective cell's value
string textValue = row.Cells[2].Text;
```

Note: cells are 0 index based. First cell is at 0 index and second cell is at 1st index and so on.

You can also try below:

```
GridViewRow row = DataShow.Rows[e.RowIndex];
String textValue = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. When i try your first solution the    catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LblSucessMsg.Text = "";
                LblErrorMsg.Text = ex.Message;

            }          Shows the error msg. " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."         When i try 2nd solution i get the "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'." error.

Comment: i tried string c = Datashow.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); This shows the index 0 of the row. and that contains the ID . but i need to get the name of the product which is on the index 1 .